How to make the jenkins build to download html artifact if clicked
I have used below code to attach an html file as artifact to my jenkins build
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'allureOne/singlehtmlfile/index.html', fingerprint: true , allowEmptyArchive: true

And it works :

Problem now is, If I click on index.html, it tries to open the file instead of downloading it. (Unlike the .zip artifacts). So the only way to download is to right click the link and do a 'save link as'.
Is there a way to disable directly opening the html file on click and instead force it to download?
No helpful info on the official docs - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/

That's browser behavior and not Jenkins behavior. When your browser sees a file that it can open it generally tries to open instead of downloading.
